# How to fix 'stderr: kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Toolbox>' error in kivy-python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, error-handling, kivy

I am trying to build a UI while following the book "kivy interactive applications with python" and I got stuck with this static code which I copied word to word.

This is the main file:

## File name: comiccreator.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

Builder.load_file('toolbox.kv')
Builder.load_file('drawingspace.kv')
Builder.load_file('generaloptions.kv')
Builder.load_file('statusbar.kv')

class ComicCreator(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class ComicCreatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ComicCreator()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ComicCreatorApp().run()
```

and then the .kv files

## File name: toolbox.kv

```
ToolBox:

<ToolButton@ToggleButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 48, 48
    group: 'tool'

<ToolBox@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    padding: 2
    ToolButton:
        text: 'O'
    ToolButton:
        text: '?'
    ToolButton:
        text: '/'
```

## File name: drawingspace.kv

```
DrawingSpace:

<DrawingSpace@RelativeLayout>:
    Label:
        markup: True
        text: '[size=32px][color=#3e6643]The[/color] [sub]Comic[/sub][i][b][Creator[/b][/i][/size]'
```

## File name: generaloptions.kv

```
GeneralOptions:

<GeneralOptions@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: 2
    Button: 
        text: 'Clear'
    Button:
        text: 'Remove'
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Group'
    Button:
        text: 'Color'
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Gestures'
```

## File name: statusbar.kv

```
StatusBar:

<StatusBar@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: 'Total Figures: ?'
    Label:
        text: "Kivy Started"
```

error message:

```
stderr: kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Toolbox>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code provided does not produce any error. Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Comment: That you for your reply @ikolim I don't understand then, why it is giving me error

Comment: Could you please provide the Kivy log and Python trace back.

Comment: thank you for all your help, the problem is solved now, it was just a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

just delete

`ToolBox:`
from top of the toolbox.kv